# delete image after 5 sec using qt creator

Tags: qt

I loaded an image using qt creator C++ :

`inputImg=new QImage("C:/Bimap/HUD1.bmp")`

and can see on the window. I want to delete this image after 5 Sec and load another image.

Is it possible to do it? Thanks for answer.

Comment: Use `QTimer`. Also remember that absolute paths like `"C:/Bimap/HUD1.bmp"` is often not a good idea, though i think you know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allocate the images in the constructor (or at least only once), and then use an index to select them.
I also added a `numImages` variable, so that you can have more than 2 images to rotate through.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
    timer->start(5000);

    index = 0;
    numImages = 2;

    inputImages[0] = new QImage("C:/Bimap/HUD1.bmp");
    inputImages[1] = new QImage("C:/Bimap/speed.bmp");
}
void MainWindow::update()
{
    showImage(inputImages[index]);
    index = ++index % numImages;
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer.It did not work.Should i also write something in main class ?How can i  showImage define?Should i also create void MainWindow::showImage?

Answer (score 2):

you need to do something like this (for example in MainWindow):

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
    timer->start(5000);

    index = 0;

    flag = false;
}
void MainWindow::update()
{
     if(flag)
         inputImg=new QImage("C:/Bimap/HUD1.bmp");
     else
         inputImg=new QImage("C:/Bimap/speed.bmp");
     flag = !flag;



}
```

Comment: thanks for answer.I have two different imagesC:/Bimap/HUD1.bmp and C:/Bimap/speed.bmp. I want them lchange from window every 5 sec.Should i write another function like update2 for second picture?

Comment: use a flag for this purpose

Comment: Be careful to also delete the `QImages`, otherwise you will get in big trouble very soon.

Comment: This code works but i cannot see imagen o the window.It shows just main window.

Comment: you need to show your image somehow. You should first be able to load and show an image, then ask this question. For show image there is [some example in Qt Creator Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-imageviewer.html).